# Variable not within scope using HttpWebRequest and WebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-error

I am having an issue with my variable httpRes. Basically this is the basics of a command line app that will check a set of given URL's and return their status code, i.e. unauthorized, redirect, ok etc. The problem is one of the apps within my list keeps throwing an error. So I used a try catch clause to catch the error and tell me what caused it.

Unfortunately the variable httpRes works in the try clause, but not in the catch. It keeps being returned as null. I called httpRes outside of the try/catch statement so I am hoping my scope is correct but for whatever reason the value never changes from null for the catch statement, only the try statement.

Here is the code referenced.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace URLMonitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
            string url1 = "https://google.com"; //removed internal URL for security reasons.
            HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url1);
            httpReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            HttpWebResponse httpRes = null;

            try
            {
                httpRes = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();
                if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Website is OK");
                    // Close the response.
                    //httpRes.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (httpRes != null)
                {
                    if (httpRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Things are not OK");
                        //httpRes.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please check the URL and try again..");
                    //httpRes.Close();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you catch an exception, that would probably be because GetResponse failed, right? So you wouldn't have assigned anything to `httpRes` yet...

It seems to me that you should be catching `WebException`, at which point you can look at the response - if there is one:

```
catch (WebException e)
{
    // We're assuming that if there *is* a response, it's an HttpWebResponse
    httpRes = (HttpWebResponse) e.Response;
    if (httpRes != null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's pretty much *never* worth writing a bare `catch` block, btw - always at least catch `Exception`, but ideally catch a more specific exception type anyway, unless you're at the top level of your application stack.

Personally I wouldn't bother using the same variable for both pieces of code - I'd declare the response for the success case within the try block, and the response for the failure case in the catch block. Also note that you should normally be disposing of your `WebResponse`, e.g.

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    // Use the response
}
```

I don't believe you need to do this if `GetResponse` throws an exception and you obtain the response from the exception.

Comment: That was the fix. So apparently I was not catching that specific error. I assumed a generic catch all would catch any exception instead of me having to specify which exception I am attempting to catch.

Comment: @stack-flo: Yes, it *will* catch any exception (it caught the one that was thrown) - but you were catching it without specifying a variable, which meant you couldn't use the information in the exception... and without specifying which exception type to use, you couldn't use the exception-type-specific property.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the thorough explanation!